# Can I run asp.net code on a PHP server?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a domain using Php but I added asp.net code. And try to execute that it displayed asp.net code only. Whether it is possible to add asp.net code under php domain by using any plugin or some third party help. If yes means, give some idea.

Comment: Just corrected some grammar and made the heading more SO friendly

Answer (score 0):

You could use HttpWebRequest to get a result off a PHP page which might help you a bit. An example taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9818700/4068558

```
string myRequest = "abc=1&pqr=2&lmn=3";
string myResponse="";
string myUrl = "Where you want to post data";
System.IO.StreamWriter myWriter = null;// it will open a http connection with provided url
System.Net.HttpWebRequest objRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(myUrl);//send data using     objxmlhttp object
objRequest.Method = "GET";
objRequest.ContentLength = TranRequest.Length;
objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";//to set content type
myWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
myWriter.Write(myRequest);//send data
myWriter.Close();//closed the myWriter object

System.Net.HttpWebResponse objResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();//receive the responce from     objxmlhttp object 
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new     System.IO.StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    myResponse= sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Otherwise, the problem is IIS will see a .php file and compile it with PHP. Vice versa with ASP. Although a work around for running PHP inside ASP.NET is [phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com).

Comment: How to use HttpWebRequest and please where to use that